# Data in one table affects another

Tags: database, entities, relational

I'm attempting to create a relational database for a tech company who perform sales, leases and offer support. I must store data for each of these, but the items that they are selling have the potential to be hardware or software based. This means that for sales that relate to hardware, a delivery address must be stored, whereas this would not be required for software.

So far I have attempted modelling this conceptually and have decided to have tables "sales", "leasing" and "support". Then linking to this, I have "product", which will have an id and generic product information, linking to separate "hardware" and "software" tables.

Part of the conceptual model

[image]

My concern is that if the product is hardware-based, the sales/leasing/support table's attributes would need to be different to allow for an address entry.

This has left me really stuck with how to model this part, and I would really appreciate any input that anyone could give.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is vague. Also it is more or less just a pile of entities without relationships/associations on them. "Related" & "linked" are not helpful terms. A table represents a relationship/assocation on some entities/values; when participants must also participate elsewhere a FK represents that *fact/constraint* ("relationship"/"link"). What *information modeling & database design reference* are you using? Please give a proper ERD or DDL that although maybe not optimal actually records a sufficiently problematic part of the data you want. Then we can talk about transforming it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look into **normalization** more and see if this answers your question. I think you should focus on one problem point and really expand on it with data/explanation/ERD to show us what data is available in what scenarios.

Let me expand some assumptions on what you said:

> This means that for sales that relate to hardware, a delivery address must be stored, whereas this would not be required for software.

So let's say a PRODUCT is SOLD. The "**Sale**" is an entity that holds information such as

- Date of sale
- Price sold
- Qty

Then, if the product is *hardware* or *software*, extra data is stored. Let's say you only store extra details for *hardware* - namely, a delivery address:

- Delivery address (stored for hardware sales only)

So it sounds like "**Sale_Hardware**" is a sub-entity of "**Sale**".

PRODUCT ---> SALE (one product can have many sales, but one sale can only have one product) - see note below.

SALE ----- SALE_HARDWARE (this is a one to one relationship, and SALE_HARDWARE will only have data for some SALEs which are hardware based).

--

Note: This is a very simplistic example. Above I mentioned that PRODUCT ---> SALE (one to many) but in reality this wouldn't be true. A sale can contain many products. That is why a SALE or ORDER is usually divided into ORDER_ITEMS and each ORDER_ITEM contains a single PRODUCT.

Hope this makes sense, and I hope this touches on how to design your database using normalization. Let me know if you have questions, or if you want to change your question to focus on a specific few entities that you want to further normalize.

Answer (score 0):

It's missing a lot of details, but I would go for something like that.  Obviously you need to fill in the gaps!

So you get a product table, a customer table.  The Hardware - Software does not realy mater, but if you must, add a Type column to your products.

A line is one product with quantity.  An Order is a bunch of lines grouped together.  Then again, a Lease is also a bunch of lines grouped together, but with additional conditions then a sale.

```
Product
    Productid
    ProductName
    Price
    ToShip: boolean, can this product be shipped or not?
    ....
Customer
    Customerid
    Firstname
    Lastname
    ShippingAddress
    BillingAddress
    Phone
    ...
```

---

```
Order
    Orderid
    Buyer: FK to Customer.Customerid
    ShippingAddress: boolean, true == use address from Customer
                              false == use address here
    ShiptoAddress
    Shipped
    TrackingNumber
Line
    Lineid
    Productid: FK to Product.Productid
    Quantity
    DiscountPercentage
Order <-> Line
    Orderid: FK to Order.Orderid
    Lineid: FK to Line.Lineid
```

---

```
Lease
    Leaseid
    Leaser: FK to Customer.Customerid
    Terms
    ...
Lease <-> Line
    Leaseid: FK to Lease.Leaseid
    Lineid: FK to Line.Lineid
```

---

```
Support: support contract
    Supportid
    Term
    SuportLevel
    ...
Support <-> Line
    Supportid: FK to Support.Supportid
    Lineid: FK to Line.Lineid
```

---

Lease could be linked to another table that specifies the LeaseType (standard conditions, lease agreement, ...).  Something similar for Support.

This allows the same product to be purchased, leased or supported.

Just ideas, adapt as required.